# Checkbox Alert Controller - Show image

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic2, ionic3

I make one application with IONIC-2 Beta version. i 'm use Checkbox Alert Controller, and want to add image like,

[image: this]

my code is

```
showCheckbox() {
let alert = this.alertCtrl.create();
alert.setTitle('Which planets have you visited?');

alert.addInput({
  type: 'checkbox',
  label: 'Alderaan',
  value: 'value1',
  checked: true
});

alert.addInput({
  type: 'checkbox',
  label: 'Bespin',
  value: 'value2'
});

alert.addButton('Cancel');
alert.addButton({
  text: 'Okay',
  handler: data => {
    console.log('Checkbox data:', data);
    this.testCheckboxOpen = false;
    this.testCheckboxResult = data;
  }
});
alert.present();
```

}

is it possible to add image like this??

If anyone knows the solution, please help me.

Thanks.

Comment: @TedNyberg :i tried above code and  follow this [documentation](http://ionicframework.com/docs/v2/api/components/alert/AlertController/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm afraid that's not possible with the `AlertController`. You could use the `ModalController` ([info](http://ionicframework.com/docs/v2/api/components/modal/ModalController/)) to present a custom page and in that page you could use a [Grid](http://ionicframework.com/docs/v2/components/#grid) to create that layout, but in terms of *look and feel* the result will be slightly different.

Comment: Just use the Modal Controller and got the same. thanks @sebaferreras : u got +1. Thanks a lot genius. :)

Comment: Glad I could help :)

Answer (score 1):

Actually you can add the image as html tags in message.  [Here's](https://forum.ionicframework.com/t/adding-image-to-alert-controller/178648) the answer that helped me do this.